# Annotating inherited properties for persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, spring

Assuming I have a class A as follows:

```
class A{
   int id;
   int getId(){};
   void setId(int id){};
}
```

And a class B as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="B")
class B extends A{
   string name;

   @Column(length=20)
   string getName(){}
   void setName(){}
}
```

How can I annotate the inherited id field from A so that Hibernate/JPA knows it is the Id
 for the entity?  I tried simply placing @Id on the field in A but this didn't work.  I 
tried making A an entity as well and this also didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the superclass itself to represent an entity, you can use `@MappedSuperclass` on the super class to have subclasses inherit the properties for persistence:

```
@MappedSuperclass
class A{
   int id;
   @Id
   int getId(){};
   void setId(int id){};
}
```

Consider making the superclass abstract.  See [this section](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e939) of the doc for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of strategies you can use. Here is something you can try:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class A{
   int id;

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   int getId(){};
   void setId(int id){};
}


@Entity
@Table(name="B")
class B extends A{
   string name;

   @Column(length=20)
   string getName(){}
   void setName(){}
}
```